# How to get sg_message_id with cakephp SMTP email

Tags: cakephp-2.3, sendgrid

How can I get "sg_message_id" value when email is sent from Cakephp email component using Sendgrid SMTP option.
I want this to track the events provided by sendgrid. This can be done by sg_message_id only. If there is any other solution then please help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the id back during the SMTP transaction. You'll need to setup the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html); the Processed events will include the `sg_message_id`.

Comment: I have setup webhook url to get the response. But to track the email we need a unique key match. So how we will get this unique key by which we can match this with the response sent from event web hook.

Comment: [SendGrid Unique Arguments](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html)